# IBAction in table cell view won't be fired

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, ibaction

I am making my first Mac OS X application and I'm stuck with a problem.

I created a NSTableView on my window linked to a NSArrayController and I'd like to call a method after stopping to edit a textfield cell. So I've selected to call an action when end editing, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

After, I've created an IBAction for it:

It generated this code in my AppDelegate.h:

```
- (IBAction)stopEditingHeaderNameCell:(id)sender;
```

And then I edited the IBAction in AppDelegate.m in order to show a NSLog message when the cell is edited:

```
- (IBAction)stopEditingHeaderNameCell:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

However, when I stop editing the cell by pressing enter or clicking in another element, nothing happens. I already tried to apply this IBAction to a NSTextField and it works perfectly, but it doesn't call the IBAction when applied to this text field cell.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way you do this with text field cells in a table view. You need to make your app delegate the delegate of the table (you can connect this in IB), and then implement controlTextDidEndEditing:.  This method will be called when you end editing (by tabbing out of the cell or clicking on another row or column).

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm. Now I am trying to get some properties of the NSNotification parameter (obj) that is sent to this function. I tried to get some informations like [obj value] but I get some errors like: "-[NSConcreteNotification key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcf90d66150" and 
"Exception detected while handling key input". How can I catch some informations like its value, row number and stuff, so I could manipulate other cells of its row based on its content?

Comment: [obj object] will give you a reference to the table view, so you can use [[obj object] selectedRow] to find out which row was selected. This line: [[obj.userInfo valueForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"] string] will get you the new string value.

Comment: Although [[obj.userInfo valueForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"] string] is returning the new content successfully, [[obj object] selectedRow] is returning "(null)" when I print it with `NSLog(@"%@", [tableView selectedRow]);`. P.S.: I stored [obj object] in a variable called tableView by using `NSTableView *tableView = (NSTableView *)[obj object];`

Comment: Forget about it. I was trying to print [tableView selectedRow] as a NSString when it's actually a NSInteger. Thank you for the help!